# What point of same properites at that json?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, api

When I get this `json` at `POST` method I need create a object. But I can't see what I need do exactly with  this code. Why there is a lot of same properties? Are they a object of different class in fields class?or what? If they are why not like that `host:{ "value":"120.515.151.124"}`. Could someone help or show some documents about that?

```
{
"fields": [
    {
        "name": "host",
        "value": "102.164.152.128"
    },
    {
        "name": "port",
        "value": "8564"
    },
    {
        "name": "accessKey",
        "value": 
"(here is a 64 bit a key like(531b8e6c...)"
    },
    {
        "name": "secretKey",
        "value": 
"(also here is a 64 bit a key like(531b8e6c...)"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Where do you get this JSON string? Have you asked the people producing it why it is shaped like that?

Comment: Actually ı asked why is like that and my questions at the topic bu the answer was that "You creating a node(name of object) that's all."

Comment: This is definitely poorly designed Json but I don't really see what kind of answer you expect.

Comment: "But I can't see what I need do exactly with this code" Well, what do you want to do?

Comment: Creating a java object from this JSON can be done by iterating over the elements in the `fields` array and switching over the `name` to assign the `value` to the appropriate field of your object. Their design gives you more work in addition to wasting bandswidth, but if you can't have them change their format it's nothing insurmounable either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fields` is an array of key value pairs.. So, this object will contain a `fields` object, which is a `map`. Can you try like this..

```
public class MyClass {
Map<String, String> fields;
}
```